# How to view when page was last refreshed in Firefox

Tags: firefox

Is there a way to know when the last time a page was refreshed in Firefox? I always have lots of tabs open. For certain pages, it would be helpful to know when it was last refreshed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the tools fly out menu there is a "page info option", under modified, it tells the exact time

Comment: This is the last modified date of the file that the web server reports.  It isn't the time the page was last refreshed.